# Grease pencil drawing underneath rough sketch?

Tags: grease-pencil

so I've tried two different times to follow this worthikids tutorial for basic 2d animation but I keep hitting the same roadblock.
I get to the part where I've drawn a rough sketch, and then you're supposed to add a new blank grease pencil to 'ink' over the roughs but it always draws underneath instead. I'm clearly doing something wrong but I don't know what.
(green is my rough layer and grey is my ink)
[image]

I tried adding a stroke instead of blank but it still does the same thing. I'm really lost here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get the result.

The "standard" method is to create Layers, where the upper layers are in front and the bottom ones are back (this happens in default mode, where the strokes depth order is set to "2D layers").

Every layer has its opacity setting, and in edit mode you can select and move strokes between layers.

In edit mode you can also arrange the strokes internal order of appearance.

In your method, using 2 different grease pencil objects, the strokes lie in the same exact place and they conflict each other (this is called Z-fighting), you should move backward one of the objects (or the single strokes), but you would get parallax shifts when working in perspective view.

[image]